# Program with phreads works for some time and then stops

Tags: c++, pthreads

I am struggling with a program that uses pthreads. Here is a simplified version of the code I have difficulties with:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>

pthread_t* thread_handles;
pthread_mutex_t mutex;
pthread_cond_t  cond_var = PTHREAD_COND_INITIALIZER;
int thread_count;
const int some_count = 76;
const int numb_count = 5;
int countR = 0;

//Initialize threads
void InitTh(char* arg[]){
    /* Get number of threads */
    thread_count = strtol(arg[1], NULL, 10);
    /*Allocate space for threads*/
    thread_handles =(pthread_t*) malloc (thread_count*sizeof(pthread_t));
}

//Terminate threads
void TermTh(){
    for(long thread = 0; thread < thread_count; thread++)
        pthread_join(thread_handles[thread], NULL);
    free(thread_handles);
}

//Work for threads
void* DO_WORK(void* replica) {
    /*Does something*/
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex);
    countR++;
    if (countR == numb_count) pthread_cond_broadcast(&cond_var);
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex);
    pthread_exit(NULL);
}

//Some function
void FUNCTION(){
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex, NULL);
    for(int k = 0; k < some_count; k++){
        for(int j = 0; j < numb_count; j++){
            long thread = (long) j % thread_count;
            pthread_create(&thread_handles[thread], NULL, DO_WORK, (void *)j);;
        }
        /*Wait for threads to finish their jobs*/
        while(pthread_cond_wait(&cond_var,&mutex) != 0);
        countR = 0;
        /*Does more work*/
    }
    pthread_cond_destroy(&cond_var);
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex);
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {    
    /*Initialize threads*/
    InitTh(argv);

    /*Do some work*/
    FUNCTION();

    /*Treminate threads*/
    TermTh();

    pthread_exit(NULL);
}
```

When `some_count`, (in this particular case,) is less than 76, the program works fine, but if I specify a larger value the program works for some time and then stalls. Maybe somebody can point what am I doing wrong?

P.S. this is my first post of this sort ever and I am obviously a newbie, so please be forgiving. :)

Comment: In addition to what Tony The Tiger said, even when you lock the mutex in `FUNCTION`, make sure you check the value if the condition variable (`countR`) **before** even attempting to wait on it. It is possible that condition is already fulfilled even before you call `pthread_cond_wait`, which would then lead to infinite wait if you actually go ahead and call `pthread_cond_wait`.

Comment: I've merged your unregistered account into your registered one. You now own your question again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From this:

> The pthread_cond_wait() and pthread_cond_timedwait() functions are
>   used to block on a condition variable. They are called with mutex
>   locked by the calling thread or undefined behaviour will result.

I understand the mutex should be locked when this function is being called, from your code I can see that this is most likely not the case.  Undefined Behavior results when calling with the mutex unlocked.

Answer (score 1):

It seems you are creating multiple threads at the same memory location one after the other (in case `numb_count` is greater than `thread_count`). The code has many other bugs -- you should almost never use `pthread_exit` (almost never use `exit()` also), and use `pthread_join` instead.